# Unable to deploy snapshot artifact

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am unable to deploy a snapshot artifact to Nexus Repository. I keep getting return code 400.
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact net.iin:iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:jar:iin-parent from/to snapshots (http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/net/iin/iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/iin-parent/iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-iin-parent.jar. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase:Bad Request.
ERROR: Uploading file iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar failed.

**But the same way I am able to deploy a snapshot artifact to Nexus Repository.**
Uploading artifact iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started....
GroupId: net.iin
ArtifactId: iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Classifier: 
Type: jar
Version: iin-parent
File: iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Repository:releases
Uploaded: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/net/iin/iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/iin-parent/iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-iin-parent.jar (63 MB at 46 MB/s)
Uploading artifact iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar completed.
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Please show your pom file in particular the are distributionManagement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you used the artifactId `iin-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. So you probably put the version into the artifactId instead of the version tag.

The result is that Maven considers your (broken) GAV as release version because the version itself does not end in SNAPSHOT.